# How to set TeXShop to open previously closed tex files?

Tags: mac, texshop

I usually work on many tex files at the same time using TeXShop (they are all in the same window but different tabs).  However, when I restart TeXShop I have to reopen all the tex files manually again to continue my work.  This is usually happen when I restart TeXShop for an update.

I want to have a functionality of opening the last tabs closed just like in many web browsers.  Is it possible to do it?

BTW, I use Mac OS X

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! I'm running TeXShop 4.73. From the Help menu, I select Changes, and see something under the second bullet point for version 4.72 that may address this. The referenced setting is under your Mac's System Preferences rather than in TeXShop's Preferences. Is this helpful?

Comment: That works many thanks

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I converted the comment to an answer, which you can accept if you find it accurate and useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my comment, this functionality is controlled by a setting under the macOS System Preferences rather than in TeXShop's Preferences. Look under System Preferences, General, and uncheck the box next to "Close windows when quitting app" to get the desired behavior.